# Google map is not displaying in my program

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm new to Android programming now I am working on Maps.
It's my first sample program in Android at all.
I get key from google console and I gave permissions in the manifest file so this is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

The output is

[image]

I searched so many websites and I found nothing for my error

Comment: Which part of this did you expect to display a map?  Your posted code is only about permissions.

Comment: Mind that, if you are targetting Android 6.0+, you'll have to request **runtime permissions**.

Comment: I didn't do anything on code just I am using predefined google map activity. Through link is given in google_maps_api.xml    I am running my program.                                                                                            
                                                                                                          
   LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

Comment: Have you generated API key for you app in Google Developer console??

Comment: Yeah I generated API key

Answer (score 0):

You must add to manifest this code for enable google maps:

```
<application>
<!--Google MAP API key-->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
</application>
```

And ensure you have the corrects SHA-1 and API Key

Comment: I added your code in the manifest file and there is no change showing like that only.And how I ensure SHA-1 and API key

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your wonderful support I tried to solve this problem but
I think while generating the key Maybe I did wrong.
So I generate another key it works.My suggestion does proper process while generating the key.